# What is the logical error that I am missing?

Tags: python, file

I am experimenting a bit with files when it comes to Python (I'm a beginner to Python) and I have run into what seems to be a logical error.

I am reading in two lines from a file, I am comparing the first line with a string, I am comparing the second line with a string.

The first line is identical to the string, The second line is also identical to the string.

The "admin_details.txt" file has two lines.

The first line is: "kappa"

The second line is: "opieop"

If I enter in "kappa" as the username and "opieop" as the password, 
this "if lines[0] == username and lines[1] == password" should be True and it should indeed execute the code "log_in_details = True", but it is not.

```py
log_in_details = False
username = ""
password = ""
details = []

while log_in_details == False:

    username = input("\n< Username >: ")
    password = input("< Password >: ")

    f = open("admin_details.txt", "r")

    lines = f.readlines()
    print(f"\nThe first line 'lines[0]' in the file is: {lines[0]}", end='')
    print(f"The second line 'lines[1]' in the file is: {lines[1]}")

    print(f"\nEntered username is: {username}")
    print(f"Entered password is: {password}")

    if lines[0] == username and lines[1] == password:
        log_in_details = True
    else:
        print("\nYou entered in the wrong username or password.")
        print("Try again!")

    f.close()
```

I expect the program to go into the first block of code right under the if-statement, change log_in_details to True and then the program will exit the while loop and the program will quit returning 0. It is not doing this, it is instead going into the block of code right under the else and goes back to the top of the while-loop.

Comment: Is it possible that one of the string values has a trailing space at the end? Try running `.strip()` on your strings when comparing.

Comment: @LucaBezerra I have checked that and there is nothing unwanted in the .txt file. Perhaps there could be something in the actual string variables. Adding .strip() did work though! Though I am still wondering why it does not work without .strip(). As I said in the .txt file there are no trailing spaces or anything like that, so the only thing I can imagine being the problem is with the actual strings "username" and "password".

Comment: Have tried doing `print(lines)`, most probably at the end of each string in that list there is a line separator `\n`.

Comment: can you show the file that it happens on?

Comment: @StamKaly Yes! Doing print(lines) returns " ['kappa\n', 'opieop'] " which would explain why "lines[0] == username" would return False when compared to username = "kappa". Thank you!

Comment: _The first line is: "kappa"_ No, it isn't.  Since you're using `readlines()`, the first line is actually `kappa\n`.

Comment: @NotSoShabby See my return comment to StamKaly.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, this I learned just now after seeing StamKaly's comment. I had no idea that there were line separators in there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as given is above, but how does one test that?

A possibility is to add single quotes:

```
print(f"\nThe first line 'lines[0]' in the file is: '{lines[0]}'", end='')
print(f"The second line 'lines[1]' in the file is: '{lines[1]}'")
```

output:

```
D:\TEMP>python admin_details.py

< Username >: kapp
< Password >: opiekop

The first line 'lines[0]' in the file is: 'kappa
'The second line 'lines[1]' in the file is: 'opiekop
'

Entered username is: kapp
Entered password is: opiekop

You entered in the wrong username or password.
Try again!
```

Notice the position of the single quotes.

Comment: _but how does one test that?_ Use `repr()`.  `print(repr(lines[0]))`